# Ubuntu 13.04 left click not working after a while

Tags: 13.04, mouse, hp-pavilion

only left click of touchpad and usb mouse not working right mouse click works.....Hp Pavilion dv6000

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug found in Ubuntu.
First open the terminal and type :

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:raof/aubergine
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get upgrade

On completion of the update restart your computer and done!

**Another solution**
Install the **deb** file from the following link.

For x86 systems : http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/xserver-xorg-input-evdev-udeb_2.7.0+git20120504.f28507e8-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise_i386.udeb

For x64 systems : http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/xserver-xorg-input-evdev-udeb_2.7.0+git20120504.f28507e8-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise_amd64.udeb

Comment: Do you know why `sudo apt-get repository ppa:raof/aubergine` helps? Will some Debian files be automoatically installed because one added another repository? And those files fixes some mouse related bug?

Comment: After adding the PPA, an UPGRADE command is executed. It installs the newer version of the affected packages

Comment: Dependency is not satisfiable libc6-udeb (>= 2.15) error when installing the deb file for x86 systems